# Best way to run a Python web application locally

Tags: python, localhost, pylons

I'm considering several options for the user interface of an application.

I want this application to be multi-platform (Windows, Linux, OSX), so one of the options I considered was to develop it as a web application, but run it on a local server to still have access to administrator privileges (which are required). simply, a web interface to my program.

I want to develop in python for convenience reasons.

Does using Pylons for this job is recommended and if so, what is the best way to run it in this setup?

Comment: A couple of questions: is this an application you plan on distributing for other users, or just an internal application for your use or as a method of testing/dog-fooding your web application? Do you want the application to have its own browser/interface, or are you looking to just run a customized webserver app and access your app via a standard web browser?

Comment: It supposed to be distributed. I want it to run on a regular browser, I just need to run it the webserver locally because I need permissions to do several actions which are not available by just hosting the app on a remote server. When the user launches the app, I want it to open a web page served from his machine, that is able to perform actions that are more complex than a web app can do when running on a browser (similar to regular program installed on the OS). I hope this made it more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). The framework itself is very easy to set up, learn, and use, and it provides an easy way to [distribute your app as a binary](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/12#How-to-Distribute-your-Applications-as-Binaries). The user would simply unzip it and click run, and it will run as a standalone app in the browser on the user's machine. It even includes its own Python interpreter, so the user doesn't have to have Python installed (very helpful on Windows, which does not typically have Python installed). The built-in [Rocket server](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rocket) will be more than adequate for running locally (some people even use it in production). You can also use Rocket with other frameworks. If you need help, ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the micro webdevelopment framework [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).
From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def hello_world(): 
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Save it as hello.py or something similar and run it with your Python interpreter.

> $ easy_install Flask
>   $ python hello.py
>      * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: This seems like another web framework such as pylons and django, I'm more interested on the way to run the web app I develop. I don't know if the development server of this frameworks is enough, and of course that I don't want a full blown web server. What I'm wondering if there is a simple python web server, that will be able to run the web app in a stable and secure way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [PySimpleGUI](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI) is what you look for.
You don't need to write any HTML and in fact with the same Python programming interface you
can create a window application or a web application.

Web server is also included, no need of extra dependencies